# Multiple queries in Php and the result is in different json per query and display in android (TextView from another Activity) using Volley library

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, android-volley

In ANDROID, i have LoginActivity and GradeActivity.

In LoginActivity, the user logged-in his/her student account. When the user successfully access his/her account, then he/she will be directed to "GradeActivity".

In GradeActivity, There are (3)Threee TextView, (1st)first is the student id of student. (2nd)second is the level of student then the last is for the subject + subject per grade(looping.). I have already done displaying the grade of student per subject (looping of json in TextView). What i want to get is to display the STUDENT ID, STUDENT LEVEL. How can i solve it? Help T_T

Below are my PHP CODE and the JSON Results.

```
  <?php 
  include_once('dbConnect.php');
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

  $user = 20160001;
  $query = "select student_id from table_student where student_id='$user'";
  $r=mysqli_query($con,$query);
  if(isset($r)){
        echo "success";
        include_once('dbConnect.php');
    $query = "select level_id from table_student where student_id='$user'";
    $r = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

        $result = array();
        array_push($result,array("level"=>$res['level_id']));


    echo json_encode(array("Level"=>$result));


    if(7==$res['level_id']){

        include_once('dbConnect.php');
        $query = "select * from table_studentsubject_grade7 where student_id='$user'";
        $res = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        $result = array();
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            array_push($result,
            array('subject_code'=>$row[0],
            '1st_qtr'=>$row[1],
            '2nd_qtr'=>$row[2],
            '3rd_qtr'=>$row[3],
            '4th_qtr'=>$row[4],
            'final'=>$row[5]
            ));
        }

        echo json_encode(array("Subjects"=>$result));

        mysqli_close($con);

    }else if(8==$res['level_id']){

        include_once('dbConnect.php');
        $query = "select * from table_studentsubject_grade8 where student_id='$user'";
        $res = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        $result = array();
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            array_push($result,
            array('subject_code'=>$row[0],
            '1st_qtr'=>$row[1],
            '2nd_qtr'=>$row[2],
            '3rd_qtr'=>$row[3],
            '4th_qtr'=>$row[4],
            'final'=>$row[5]
            ));
        }

        echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

        mysqli_close($con);

    }else if(9==$res['level_id']){

        include_once('dbConnect.php');
        $query = "select * from table_studentsubject_grade9 where student_id='$user'";
        $res = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        $result = array();
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            array_push($result,
            array('subject_code'=>$row[0],
            '1st_qtr'=>$row[1],
            '2nd_qtr'=>$row[2],
            '3rd_qtr'=>$row[3],
            '4th_qtr'=>$row[4],
            'final'=>$row[5]
            ));
        }

        echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

        mysqli_close($con);

    }else if(10==$res['level_id']){

        include_once('dbConnect.php');
        $query = "select * from table_studentsubject_grade10 where student_id='$user'";
        $res = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        $result = array();
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            array_push($result,
            array('subject_code'=>$row[0],
            '1st_qtr'=>$row[1],
            '2nd_qtr'=>$row[2],
            '3rd_qtr'=>$row[3],
            '4th_qtr'=>$row[4],
            'final'=>$row[5]
            ));
        }

        echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

        mysqli_close($con);

    }


    }else{
        echo "failure";
    }

}
```

Here is the JSON result that i get.

```
    success{"Level":[{"level":"7"}]}{"Subjects":[{"subject_code":"20160001","1st_qtr":"ARA15G7","2nd_qtr":"90","3rd_qtr":"90","4th_qtr":"90","final":"90"},{"subject_code":"20160001","1st_qtr":"ENG15G7","2nd_qtr":null,"3rd_qtr":null,"4th_qtr":null,"final":null},{"subject_code":"20160001","1st_qtr":"CHR15G7","2nd_qtr":null,"3rd_qtr":null,"4th_qtr":null,"final":null},{"subject_code":"20160001","1st_qtr":"FIL15G7","2nd_qtr":null,"3rd_qtr":null,"4th_qtr":null,"final":null},{"subject_code":"20160001","1st_qtr":"*MA15G7","2nd_qtr":null,"3rd_qtr":null,"4th_qtr":null,"final":null},{"subject_code":"20160001","1st_qtr":"MAT15G7","2nd_qtr":null,"3rd_qtr":null,"4th_qtr":null,"final":null},{"subject_code":"20160001","1st_qtr":"TLE15G7","2nd_qtr":null,"3rd_qtr":null,"4th_qtr":null,"final":null},{"subject_code":"20160001","1st_qtr":"SCI15G7","2nd_qtr":"88","3rd_qtr":"99","4th_qtr":"20","final":"85"}]}
```